# Where does thunderbird store the training data for its adaptive junk mail filter

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

Thunderbird has a junk filter which can learn as you mark more and more mail as junk.
I want to know what is the name of the specific file in the thunderbird profile containing the training data of said filter

Comment: I don't know the specific answer, but this page may help you http://kb.mozillazine.org/Junk_Mail_Controls

Answer (score 0):

training.dat  (not msgFilterRules.dat)

http://www.mesquilla.net/mesquillacom/extensions/junquilla/index.html gives some background on junk processing

Comment: Are you sure that's the junk filter training data rather than the message filter rules? Also, I don't have that file on mine (maybe Windows vs. Linux?).  I haven't defined any message filters, so if that's what that file is, that could explain it.

Comment: You are correct - I blame drugs :)

The correct file is training.dat in the profile directory https://support.mozilla.org/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data